# React - .setState is partially not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I need help with updating the state in React.
I am making an Encryption/Decryption form with React. This EncryptForm is rendered in App.js. What I want to do is listen to `onSubmit` function and update the isSubmitted state, then render `decipher` value under the 'Convert' button.

My question is **why `.setState` works in `handleChange` method but it doesn't work in `handleSubmit` method.** What am I missing?
(`encryptMessage` and `decryptMessage` methods are working fine.)

Here is the EncryptForm component code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import crypto from 'crypto'

class EncryptForm extends Component {
    state = {
        userInput: '',
        isSubmitted: false,
        decipher: ''
    }

    encryptMessage(input, key) {
        // Initialization Vector - 16 bytes
        const iv = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16), 'utf8')
        const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv)
        let encoded = cipher.update(input, 'utf8', 'base64')
        encoded += cipher.final('base64')
        return [encoded, iv, cipher.getAuthTag()]
    }

    decryptMessage(key, encoded, iv, authTag) {
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv)
        decipher.setAuthTag(authTag)
        let text = decipher.update(encoded, 'base64', 'utf8')
        text += decipher.final('utf8')
        return text
    }

    /*
        Non-encryption methods
    */
    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        const KEY = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(32), 'utf8')
        const [encrypted, iv, authTag] = this.encryptMessage(this.state.userInput, KEY)
        const decrypted = this.decryptMessage(KEY, encrypted, iv, authTag)
        const newState = {
            ...this.state,
            isSubmitted: true,
            decipher: decrypted
        }

        // THIS IS NOW UPDATING THE STATE :(
        this.setState({ newState })
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { userInput, isSubmitted, decipher } = this.state
        const isInvalid = userInput === ''
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    name='userInput'
                    placeholder='Encrypt this text...'
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <button disabled={isInvalid} type='submit'>Convert</button>
                {isSubmitted && <p>{decipher.value}</p>}
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default EncryptForm
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting state incorrectly in `handleSubmit`. `newState` is the entire state object, so setting it like `this.setState({ newState })` is not updating the whole state, but instead creating a new key called `newState` and setting it to what you expect the state to be. The result is something like this:

```js
state = {
  ...previous_state,
  newState: {
    ...this.state,
    isSubmitted: true,
    decipher: decrypted
  },
}
```

Instead you could do something like this to correctly update:

```js
// desctructure so it overwrites each key
this.setState({ ...newState });

// pass the non-nested object
this.setState(newState);
```

Or the preferred method would be to only update the keys necessary. `this.setState` does a shallow merge with the given object and the previous state. So you don't need to do `{...this.state}` (in fact it is discouraged).

This is the most concise and accurate way:

```js
this.setState({ isSubmitted: true, decipher: decrypted });
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I didn't know that `this.setState` does a shallow merge so that I don't need to make a copy of state object. Now my application is working great!